# Ember cli error with ember-simple-auth

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli, ember-simple-auth

I'm trying to use ember-simple-auth with a custom session. After logging in, when I try to access the session in a template, like so:

```
{{session.current_user.email}}
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion Failed: Required contextualElement for view <Ember._HandlebarsBoundView:ember375> is missing
```

if I reload the page, the error goes away. Also, if I use an unbound helper, it goes away:

```
{{unbound session.current_user.email}}
```

I have the following code to set the current_user when the user_id changes:

```
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';
import Ember from 'ember';

export function initialize(container) {
  Session.reopen({
    setCurrentUser: function() {
      var id = this.get('user_id');
      var _this = this;
      if(!Ember.isEmpty(id)) {
        return container.lookup('store:main').find('user', id).then(function(user){
          _this.set('current_user', user);
        });
      }
    }.observes('user_id')
  });
}

export default {
  name: 'authentication',
  before: 'simple-auth',
  initialize: initialize
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

### Edit #1:

Where would I put this code? An initializer? `app/sessions/custom.js`?

```
export default Session.extend({
  currentUser: function() {
    var userId = this.get('user_id');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
     return this.container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
    }
  }.property('user_id')
});
```

Then in the environment.js I set:

```
ENV['simple-auth'] = {
  session: 'session:custom'
}
```

and in the initializer I register the custom session?

```
container.register('session:custom', Session);
```

### Edit #2:

Moved custom session to `sessions/custom.js`. Still same error:

[image: Cryptic Ember Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would define a `currentUser` method on the Session that returns the user as a promise:

```
export default Session.extend({
  currentUser: function() {
    var userId = this.get('user_id');
    if (!Ember.isEmpty(userId)) {
     return this.container.lookup('store:main').find('user', userId);
    }
  }.property('user_id')
});
```

Also you should better define your own customer session class that extends from the Ember Simple Auth `Session` class instead of reopening that.

Comment: the original question, couldn't get code formatting in a comment, apparently.

Comment: You put the session into `app/sessions/custom.js` and if you're using the most recent Ember CLI you don't have to register it with the container - simply configure `ENV['simple-auth'].session = 'session:custom'`

Comment: Thanks for your help so far marcoow. Simplified a lot of my code. Still same error message though. See edit #2. Are there some special rules for accessing the session in a template?

Comment: Hm, should actually work that way, see the example here: https://github.com/simplabs/ember-simple-auth/blob/master/examples/4-authenticated-account.html#L32. Which versions of Ember, Ember Data etc. are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68945/discussion-between-kori-john-roys-and-marcoow).

Comment: running into similar issue...what was the final solution?

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what marcoow said, but we are using a promise object:

`app/initializers/simple-auth-session.js`

```
import Session from 'simple-auth/session';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default {
  name: 'simple-auth-custom-session',
  before: 'simple-auth',
  initialize: function(container) {
    Session.reopen({
      currentUser: function() {
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
          promise: container.lookup('store:main').find('user', 'me')
        });
      }.property()
    });
  }
};
```